# Using conditional statements in place of custom Page templates

Tags: page-template, conditional-content

How do I use if/ else statements instead of custom Page templates? For example, I create content for static Pages that I want to look different from other static Pages. So instead of using `page-sample.php`, `page-sample2.php`, etc, could I use conditional statements?

Is there a tutorial that would demonstrate how to do this? It seems that it would save time but I am not familiar enough with using them in WP.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Which *specific* template files do you want to avoid using?

Answer (score 1):

WordPress includes [a plethora of conditional tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) that can be used in lieu of specific template files.

For example, if you wanted to avoid using date-based archive template files, you could use something like the following in `index.php`:

```
<?php
if ( is_archive() ) { // This is a date-based archive
    if ( is_year() ) {
        // This is a year-based archive; 
        // do something
    } else if ( is_month() ) {
        // This is a month-based archive; 
        // do something
    } else if ( is_day() ) {
        // This is a day-based archive; 
        // do something
    } else {
        // I think the above three cases cover everything,
        // but this is a just-in-case, default fallback
    }
}
?>
```

Do you have specific templates for which you want to use conditionals?

Comment: It's not that I don't want to use specific template files, I want to use conditionals to avoid using custom page templates. For example, I create content for pages that I want to look different than other pages. So instead of using page-sample.php, page-sample2.php, etc, could I use conditional statements? This could also be done for different styled blog pages as well. I'm not sure if I'm making sense - maybe I should just stick with page templates?

Comment: Can you clarify your question (above) to specify *what kind of content* you want to include in your Pages?